# ¿Cómo seleccionar elementos de listas anidadas con linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Nececito optimizar este codigo a una unica consulta LINQ

Mi codigo:

```
  public IList<SucursalModel> RemoverSucursalesMalas(IList<SucursalModel> sucursales)
    {
        var sucursalesBuenas = new List<SucursalModel>();
        var cabecera = new List<SucursalCabeceraModel>();
        var detalle = new List<SucursalDetalleModel>();
        foreach(var item in sucursales)
        {
            cabecera = item.Cabecera.Where(c => c.Controla != "M").ToList();
            if (cabecera.Count > 0)
            {
                detalle = item.Detalle.Where(d => d.Controla != "M").ToList();
                if (detalle.Count > 0)
                    sucursalesBuenas.Add( item);
            }
        }

        return sucursalesBuenas;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Estás haciendo un `Select` (o `SelectMany`, en este ejemplo es irrelevante).

`Select` sirve para mapear datos de una colección a otra. Literalmente estás diciendo que se mapeen todos los elementos de la colección `resultSucursales` a una colección con todas las `Cabecera` (filtrados) de cada elemento.

Deberías devolver una copia de todo el objeto, pero con las `Cabecera` filtradas.

```
var res = sucursales.Select<Sucursal, Sucursal>(sucursal =>
{
    return new Sucursal()
    {
        Cabeceras = sucursal.Cabeceras.Where(c => c.Controla != "M").ToList(),
        Detalles = sucursal.Detalles
    };
});
```

Te dejo [aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJHUPp) el ejemplo.

Comment: ME DICE : IList<SucursalModel>' no contiene una definición para 'Select' y la mejor sobrecarga del método de extensión 'Queryable.Select<SucursalCabecera, SucursalDetalle>(IQueryable<SucursalCabecera>, Expression<Func<SucursalCabecera, SucursalDetalle>>)' requiere un receptor del tipo 'IQueryable<SucursalCabecera>'

Comment: ¿Has importado el *namespace* `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: VRoxa ...Gracias ...Voy a editar mi pregunta para una mejor comprension..por que con tu ayuda mejoro 80% lo que ya tenia

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma resolvi :

```
var sucursalesBuenas = resultSucursales.Where(x => x.Cabecera.Count(c => c.Controla != "M") > 0 
&& x.Detalle.Count(d => d.Controla != "M") > 0).ToList();
```